# Select list not displaying properly in HTML

Tags: html

I have a select list that I am attempting to display but when the select list is on the page, the "value" appears to the left of the select list option on the page. For instance, I want people to select their title "Mr. Mrs" etc. When the select list shows it displays as:

Mr."Select List Option For Mr"

The Mr. on the left is just appearing as text.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<label for ="title">Title</label>
 <select name="title">
 <option value= "Select">Choose Title</option>
 <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
  <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
   <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: I executed your code. Its displaying all values to the left. you want to change the alignment.?

Comment: Hi Devika, that would be great! What is your suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this it will helpfull.

```
<select name="title">
 <option value= "Select" selected>Mr.</option>
 <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
  <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
   <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>
```